# What are the effects of the “Bad Weapon!” status effect?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

When I equip a weapon that I don't have the skill for, I get the **Bad Weapon!** status effect. While it says, "Your attacks will be less effective until you get rid of it!", most status effects state what they do and what stats they change, but this doesn't have any more information in the tooltip.

When I'm duel wielding, Vampirism and Dwarven Handshake still proc and I don't notice any change in my primary or secondary stats. So what does **Bad Weapon!** actually do?

A quick look at the wiki (I'm mostly avoiding spoilers) and a search on Google didn't turn up anything promising.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **Bad Weapon** and **Hands Full** (the debuff for wielding two weapons without the *Dual Weilding* skill) do not affect any of your statistics, but instead cause a direct percentage loss to your damage output when using melee weapons.

*Bad Weapon* reduces damage by 28%.
*Hands Full* reduces damage by 36%.

I'm not sure how these stack (whether it's a straight 64% drop, or compounded ~54% drop).

<sub>See the [Bad Weapon](http://www.dredmorwiki.com/wiki/Bad_Weapon) page on the wiki if you want confirmation.</sub>

Comment: I don't see any different effects with dual-wielding. As a maceman wielding two swords or a sword and a mace, I only have **Bad Weapon.**

Comment: But according to the question you have the dual wielding skill, so you wouldn't get that debuff (which you get for dual wielding without the skill - regardless of the weapons used)?

Comment: Ahh. I had assumed you couldn't wield two weapons without the skill at all. I thought it meant using two unfamiliar weapons, and was different from using one good weapon and one bad.